# Can `ADD` create a control hazard while in the `MEM` stage?

Tags: mips

Imagine there is a machine that has shared memory for both data and instructions (which means a control hazard can occur between the `MEM` and `IF` stages). Can instructions such as `ADD` that do nothing during the `MEM` stage cause a control hazard with other instructions that are in the `IF` stage?

```
ADD $1, $1, $3 :       IF  ID  EX  MEM WB
SUB $4, $5, $6 :                   IF  ID  EX  MEM WB
```

In the example above, is there a control hazard between the `MEM` stage of the `ADD` instruction and the `IF` stage of the `SUB` instruction?

**Edit:** Description of the each instruction.

```
IF  - Instruction Fetch
ID  - Instruction Decode
EX  - Execute
MEM - Memory Access
WB  - Write-Back
```

Comment: Could you ate least mention which assembler syntax you are using? Are those $1 etc. registers, or could they imply memory access? I assume not, and in that case: how CAN there be a memory-related hazard when there are no memory writes??

Comment: I think you are also implying a 5 stage pipeline, that's worth mentioning as there is no standard. Also writing down what the acronyms stand for might be a good idea

Comment: @VladimirCravero Sorry, I thought they were standard.

Comment: No problem, they might be, that is not so immediate after a long day though.

Comment: So just to be clear, does $n means a memory read, or register access? If this is 'RISC' then their is only one memory access per instruction, so is WB update registers? If it is CISC with multiple memory accesses, then shouldn't EX be after MEM and before WB?

Comment: @gbulmer It is a register access. The order of the stages is the same as the one given to us in the course.

Comment: This may be obvious to you, but it is not to me, so please bare with me. If those two instructions are *only* addressing registers, then either their can't be a control hazard involving MEM, because it isn't involved; or the control hazard is caused by contention for a shared resource within the CPU, e.g. register write-back and MEM use the same bus. IS that what others understand, or have I missed a case?

Comment: @gbulmer That's exactly how I would expect the processor to work, but I wasn't sure. It could have been that the memory access unit was very simplistic and unconditionally blocked whenever an instruction was in `MEM`, regardless of whether there was any work to do or not.

Comment: Okay, I undersand your point. Hopefully these comments will help everyone get on the same page. It looks like we all agree (though that doesn't *guarantee* correctness :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional RISC pipeline with separate Fetch and Mem states is generally tailored for separate instruction and data busses (aka "Harvard"), often connected to separate Instruction and Data caches.
The purpose is being able to simultaneously do instruction fetches and data accesses, with a nice symmetry : IF for the instruction bus, MEM for the data bus.

If your RISC CPU has only one external bus, multiplexed for instructions and data, load or store instructions will stall the fetch part and incur a pipeline bubble, so that the instruction will cost 2 cycles. (An old example : Cypress 7C601)

*Back to your question*

A simple ADD instruction does nothing in the MEM stage, there is no control hazard with a subsequent SUB, or load, or store, or whatever. There may be data hazards, solved by stalling and/or bypassing, if the consecutive instructions use/depends on the same registers.

Answer (score 1):

If the memory is a single port memory, i.e. you cant read and write (from/to different locations), `IF` generally can't occur during `MEM` phase. This problem can be addressed in several ways:

- build a dual port memory: that costs a lot but eradicates the problem
- [bubble the pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_(computing)): there's some more circuitry that determines if a control hazard can occur and insert some delays around to avoid that. That's somewhat costly and difficult do design
- you manually insert *a lot* of delay states in the pipeline. No "smart" circuitry needed, some registers are needed but it's really simple. Please note that in this way each instruction will require two memory accesses, IF and MEM, and that becomes a limit for speed.

In a RISC von Neumann architecture though the second option is probably the most used: the only two instructions that actually use the `MEM` status are `load` and `sto` so "bubbling" the pipeline should be, if not trivial, quite easy.

Comment: I think what you describe is a contention problem, not a hazard.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Structural_hazards) they call it "structural hazard"... That's just a name though, OP uses "control hazard" that seems to be related only to branching.